# How to show js object name and its all property value?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, for-in-loop, nested-object

I have object like this

```
var savedColor = {
    "plat1" : {
        "background" : "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "text" : "rgb(255,255,255)"
    },
    "plat2" : {
        "background" : "rgb(0,50,50)"
        "text" : "rgb(0,0,0)"
    }
}
```

I want to show the output like this:

```
plate1
rgb(0,0,0)
rgb(255,255,255)
plate2
rgb(0,50,50)
rgb(0,0,0)
```

I tried this code:

```
for(var x in savedColor){
    console.log(savedColor[x]);
    for(var y in savedColor[x]){
        console.log(savedColor[y]);
    }
}
```

But the output is not showing like what i want.The output:

```
[Object object]
undefined
undefined
[Object object]
undefined
undefined
```

How can i show the output   like I told above?

Comment: What is `saved`, shouldn't that be `savedColor`?

Comment: `saved[y]` should be `saved[x][y]`

Comment: And if you want to see the key `plat1` you should log `x`, not `saved[x]`.

Comment: It was a typing mistake!

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `for ... in` to iterate keys and `for ... of` to iterate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` to get the outer key (which you can print) and the object, and then iterate over the `Object.values` of the inner object and print that:

```js
var savedColor = {
    "plat1" : {
        "background" : "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "text" : "rgb(255,255,255)"
    },
    "plat2" : {
        "background" : "rgb(0,50,50)",
        "text" : "rgb(0,0,0)"
    }
}
for (const [key, obj] of Object.entries(savedColor)) {
  console.log(key);
  for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```